# Filter a laravel collection inside a view by comparing dates?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-collection

I am trying to filter a collection of objects by comparing date its expiry date with today's date but I cant quite get it to work. Can anyone take a look at the code. I'm sure i'm missing something here. I have searched all over and found alot of examples but none are working.

This complies just fine but with a list of 9 objects 3 of which have an expiry date which is set to 2012 it doesn't return any results from the collection.

**Controller**

```
public function classifieds()
{   
    $myclassifieds = Auth::user()->classifieds;
    return view('account.classifieds')->with(['allclassifieds'=>$myclassifieds]);
}
```

**View**

```
@if(count($allclassifieds->where('expired_on','<', Carbon\Carbon::now() ) ) > 0)
//Something here
@endif
```

Comment: Looks fine, hard to say without seeing the collection itself. Are you sure that `expired_on` is available directly on the first level of each collection object? Also, `where()` comparison is strict. Could be that your `expired_on` is a date, while Carbon::now() gives you datetime - and that might cause problems, not sure.

Comment: This is the collection with one object in it. Expires_on is a date time object its very strange.
[  
   {  
      "id":31,
      "username":"test",
      "type":1,
      "action":"sell",
      "maincat":"Antiques",
      "title":"test ",
      "description":"test",
      "extratextfield":null,
      "lowerprice":1,
      "partex":0,
      "condition":"used",
      "price":"680",
      "images":"1",
      "email":"test@test.com",
      "comments":1,
      "created_at":"2016-04-03 19:00:26",
      "updated_at":"2016-04-03 19:00:26",
      "expires_on":"2016-03-14 19:00:26"
   }
]

Comment: In your code, you have `expired_on`. Is it a typo while putting this in the post or a typo in the original code? ;) The object holds `expires_on` in it.

Comment: thats my bad its actually written good in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the value `expired_on` directly

```
@foreach($allclassifieds as $classified)
    @if($classified->expired_on > Carbon\Carbon::now())
        // show classified
    @endif
@endforeach
```

You can make the expired_on property a Carbon instance by default by adding it to the `$dates` array in your model:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'expired_on'];
```

now `expired_on` always returns a Carbon instance

Comment: This does actually work but I have to Carbon::parse() the $classified->expired_on to sucessfully compare. Not exactly what im looking for but its doable this way

Comment: @matpulis updated answer. Could you elaborate what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to get a count of how many items in the collections have an expires_on date smaller then today. without actually having to do a for loop. Altough your method does work. Thanks you

Comment: @matpulis oh I see. I would have the controller handle that. and send it as a variable to the view.

Comment: I did just that. Strangely enough  ->where('expired_on','<', Carbon\Carbon::now()) works good when you put it directly to the model as a query. Thanks man